# detect addition, deletion of contact in android

Tags: android

How do I detect if there was a change in the contact database in Android. 
Assuming, the application needs to trigger a function if a new contact is added or existing contact is modified or deleted.

The app need to know of any state changes to the contact database. 
Appreciate any help in this regards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a ContentObserver on Android's Contacts database.

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, [YOUR OBSERVER]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a service which will called when your apps would be launched and will compare previous contacts list with current list if there is any difference then you can show alert or pop up alert to indicate that contacts has been modified then show an option in which user can sync recent contact list by calling same query to get contacts with the help of content provider api.

just maintain number of contacts in shared preference then each time compare that numbers with number of present contact from recent query in service.then modify accordingly shared preference.